# Plotting 2 plots in two differrent axes of the same GUI window

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-guide, multiple-axes

I am trying to make two plots in the same GUI figure that has 2 different axes. I would like one plot in one axes whereas the next one in the other. However, both my plots are generated from a single function, which I call in the GUI with a push button.

When I write `axes()` before the 2nd plot inside the function, I get a third axes which is misplaced. If I omit the `axes()` call, I get both plots in the same axes. How can I plot the second graph in the second axes?

GUI

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
---------
---------
---------
axes(handles.axes1);
     kendrickplot(n,alpha,em,infile,outfile);
---------
```

Function

```
function [ynew,xnew]=kendrickplot(n,alpha,em,infile,outfile)
---------
---------
scatter(xnew,ynew,'b.')
xlim([0,max(a(:,4))])
ylim([min(a(:,5)),max(a(:,5))])
hold on
plot(xnew,n*(ones(length(xnew))),'r')
scatter(a(:,4),a(:,5))
end
```

Comment: Add the axes handle to the plotting functions `scatter` and `plot`

Comment: Try passing `handles.axes1` and `handles.axes2` to your function and calling `axes(h1);` and `axes(h2)`before each plot

Comment: @VaheTshitoyan could you please give an example of what you're suggesting?

Comment: modify your function: `function [ynew,xnew]=kendrickplot(n,alpha,em,infile,outfile, h1, h2)`. Inside the function, add `axes(h1)` before the first plot and `axes(h2)` before the 2nd plot. In your callback, call the function like this `kendrickplot(n,alpha,em,infile,outfile, handles.axes1, handles.axes2);`. Haven't tested this.

Comment: @VaheTshitoyan Yes, it works. Thank you, so much!

Comment: @Rudstar Glad it helped. I'll post it as an answer for future readers, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to pass the handles of the axes to the function that does the plotting.

1. modify your function to accept the plot handles:

   `function [ynew,xnew]=kendrickplot(n,alpha,em,infile,outfile, h1, h2)`
2. Inside the function, add `axes(h1)` before the first plot and `axes(h2)` before the 2nd plot.
3. In your callback, call the function like this `kendrickplot(n,alpha,em,infile,outfile, handles.axes1, handles.axes2);`.